# How to add your own decorator to the flask-admin panel?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am using Flask-Login for the login handling. In addition I wrote myself a decorator to keep views visible just for role=admin.

```
def admin_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if current_user.role.name == "admin":
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash("You need to be an admin to view this page.")
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return wrap
```

I can use that decorator for my routes. But I don't know how to use this decorator for my flask-admin panel.

The Flask-SQLAlchemy Models were added to the flask-admin view like:

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_admin import Admin

admin = Admin(app, name='admin', template_mode='bootstrap3')

admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Role, db.session))
```

But I want if someone who is not an admin hits: 127.0.0.1:8000/admin do not get access and gets redirected to /home.

But I have no route for my /admin and when I implement one I do not know what html I should return?

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at this, flask admin supports role based access quite well https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/#authorization-permissions

Comment: Why not just create a route for /admin? Why don't you have a route for admin?
I have handled this by putting the custom admin decorator above my admin route. Then they will get redirected to 'home' if they try to access that route (based on your decorator function)

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in method is_accessible, by deafult, it returns True, which means that admin panel will be accessible by all, you can change it by overriding it like this:

```
class MyAdminViews(ModelView):

    def is_accessible(self):
        user = User.query.filter_by(role=current_user.role).first()
        res = user.role == "admin"
        return res

admin.add_view((MyAdminViews(User, db.session)))
admin.add_view((MyAdminViews(Post, db.session)))
```

Now, these admin views will be accessible if and only if the user possesses an admin role. Also, you might want to add a clause to make it accessible only when someone is logged in, else the browser will throw an internal server error. You can do it like this:

```
class MyAdminViews(ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            user = User.query.filter_by(role=current_user.role).first()
            res = user.role == "admin"
            return res
```